# Concurrency guarantees of Weak/Soft/Phantom Reference clearing

Tags: java, reference, garbage-collection

Besides stronge references, there are three distinct "kinds of *Reference": WeakReference, SoftReference and PhantomReference. There may be others, but they will either extend one those or be irrelevant to my question.

If an object is not strongly reachable during a GC cycle, it gets garbage collected (i.e. finalized and removed from memory). But before it is collected, any *Reference is cleared - depending on reachability conditions, the kind of *Reference to be cleared, memory demand, etc.

I was wondering, if the JLS made any guarantees about whether all *References of the same kind to the same object are cleared atomically/simultaneously, or if there is a slight chance (ie. "race condition"), that some *References get cleared while other *References of the same kind are not, such that an object could potentially be revived (ie. be strongly referenced again) through one of the remaining *References although some *References of the same kind have already been cleared and enqueued.

Question rephrased from a different POV: Is it safe to assume that a cleared *Reference implies that the previously referenced object cannot be revived through a different *Reference of the same kind?

Comment: I can't give you a "hard" answer, but I know this as been a problem area for Java since the git-go.  The original design for weak references and finalizers was not well thought out, and it's not clear that attempts to fix it have been successful.

Answer (score 4):

You may refer to the documentation.

[`SoftReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html):

> [The garbage collector] may choose to **clear atomically** all soft references to that object and all soft references to any other softly-reachable objects from which that object is reachable through a chain of strong references.

[`WeakReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html):

> [The garbage collector] will **atomically clear** all weak references to that object and all weak references to any other weakly-reachable objects from which that object is reachable through a chain of strong and soft references.

The point is moot for [`PhantomReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html) because the referent cannot be retrieved from it (`get` always returns null).

Comment: True but .. still leaves a bit of wiggle room wrt if (*all* SoftReferences for a particular object, eg) will be cleared *atomically* wrt the non-GC thread. Or if one (but not all of multiple) SoftReference-not-cleared may revive an object ..

Comment: @user2864740 The docs say the clear is atomic. Where's the wiggle room? It's either atomic or it's not.

Comment: (I think) I know that the JVM is essentially frozen during a GC cycle (ie. one can assume atomicity of any GC actions wrt the memory model). My question was, if the "atomically" in the documentation entails "_any_ clearing of _all_ such *References _at once_" or only "_all_ clearing of _any_ such *Reference _on its own_". Please, state a clear answer to my originally rephrased question: Does a cleared *Reference imply, the previously referenced object cannot be revived through a *References of the same kind (or a tangling chain of *Reference of the same kind or any stronger)?

Comment: @Robin479 The documentation clearly states 'atomically clear all weak references to that object and all weak references to any other weakly-reachable objects from which that object is reachable through a chain of strong and soft references'. The references you describe in your last sentence are either included in that specification or don't exist. It won't make sense for 'atomically' to mean reference by reference separately.

Comment: I guess if you're asking if I think the phrasing used in the documentation is ambiguous, I don't think so. *"atomically clear all"* is pretty unambiguous.

Comment: To me the phrasing in the documentation is slightly ambiguous, because it depends on where you put the stress/accent in that sentence (see [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prosodic_stress]). That's why more elaborate (english) sentences other than simple subject-predicate-object forms are not a good vessel to transport information _(Hail the Web 3.0!)_, and should not appear in a specification.
My original question, if cleared *References imply that the former referent also cannot be revived otherwise, shall remain unanswered, although RTFM answers with some uncertainty have been given.